# How can you pass values from HTML to JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a Seat Booking UI kind of thing in which there is a drop-down to select an event and I want to give that event a rate and an Id from HTML here is the code-

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const seats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat:not(.occupied)');
const count = document.getElementById('count');
const price = document.getElementById('price');
const movieSelect = document.getElementById('movie');
let ticketPrice = +movieSelect.value;
const populateUI = () => {
  const selectedSeats = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedSeats'));

  if (selectedSeats !== null && selectedSeats.length > 0) {
    seats.forEach((seat, index) => {
      if (selectedSeats.indexOf(index) > -1) {
        seat.classList.add('selected');
      }
    });
  }

  const selectedMovieIndex = localStorage.getItem('selectedMovieIndex');
  const selectedMoviePrice = localStorage.getItem('selectedMoviePrice');

  if (selectedMovieIndex !== null) {
    movieSelect.selectedIndex = selectedMovieIndex;
  }

  if (selectedMoviePrice !== null) {
    count.innerText = selectedSeats.length;
    price.innerText = selectedSeats.length * +selectedMoviePrice;
  }
};

populateUI();

selectedMovie = (movieIndex, moviePrice) => {
  localStorage.setItem('selectedMovieIndex', movieIndex);
  localStorage.setItem('selectedMoviePrice', moviePrice);
};

const updateSelectedSeatsCount = () => {
  const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .selected');

  const seatsIndex = [...selectedSeats].map(seat => [...seats].indexOf(seat));

  localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats', JSON.stringify(seatsIndex));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(seatsIndex))
  const selectedSeatsCount = selectedSeats.length;

  count.innerText = selectedSeatsCount;
  price.innerText = selectedSeatsCount * ticketPrice;
};

// Seat select event
container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (
    e.target.classList.contains('seat') &&
    !e.target.classList.contains('occupied')
  ) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('selected');

    updateSelectedSeatsCount();
  }
});

// Movie select event
movieSelect.addEventListener('change', e => {
  ticketPrice = +e.target.value;
  selectedMovie(e.target.selectedIndex, e.target.value);

  updateSelectedSeatsCount();
});

const finalizeWithServer = (msg) => {
  console.log("trying to access");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(msg));
}

const btn = document.querySelector('.glow-on-hover');

btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  console.log('Button Clicked');
  const selectedSeats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .selected');

  const seatsIndex = [...selectedSeats].map(seat => [...seats].indexOf(seat));


  localStorage.setItem('selectedSeats', JSON.stringify(seatsIndex));
  let json = '{"eventId":' + 2 + ',' +
    '"Seats":' + JSON.stringify(seatsIndex) + "}"
  console.log(json);

  console.log(localStorage.getItem("selectedSeatsName"));
  //  const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //  const url='https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  //  Http.open("GET", url);
  //  Http.send();

  //  Http.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
  //  console.log(Http.responseText)
  //  }
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&display=swap');
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #242333;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

.glow-on-hover {
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #111;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.glow-on-hover:before {
  content: '';
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #ff0000, #ff7300, #fffb00, #48ff00, #00ffd5, #002bff, #7a00ff, #ff00c8, #ff0000);
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -2px;
  background-size: 400%;
  z-index: -1;
  filter: blur(5px);
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  height: calc(100% + 4px);
  animation: glowing 20s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.glow-on-hover:active {
  color: #000
}

.glow-on-hover:active:after {
  background: transparent;
}

.glow-on-hover:hover:before {
  opacity: 1;
}

.glow-on-hover:after {
  z-index: -1;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #111;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@keyframes glowing {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  50% {
    background-position: 400% 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
}

.movie-container {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.movie-container select {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.container {
  perspective: 1000px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.seatSpace {
  background-color: #242333;
  height: 12px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 3px;
}

.seat {
  background-color: #444451;
  height: 12px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 3px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  --seatName: hello;
}

.seat.selected {
  background-color: #6feaf6;
}

.seat.occupied {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.seat:not(.occupied):hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.showcase .seat:not(.occupied):hover {
  cursor: default;
  transform: scale(1);
}

.showcase {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #777;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.showcase li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.showcase li small {
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.screen {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 15px 0;
  transform: rotateX(-45deg);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

p.text {
  margin: 5px 0;
}

p.text span {
  color: #6feaf6;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <title>Seat Booking</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="movie-container">
    <label>Select a Event</label>
    <select id="movie">
      <option value="10" dbid="2">Sport's Day 6th - 10th (10₹)</option>
      <option value="10" dbid="3">Sport's Day 2st - 5nd (10₹)</option>
      <option value="15" dbid="4">GrandParents Day nursery - 1st (15₹)</option>
      <option value="15" dbid="5">GrandParents Day 2st - 5nd (15₹)</option>
      <option value="15" dbid="6">GrandParents Day 6th - 10th (15₹)</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <ul class="showcase">
    <li>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <small>N/A</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="seat selected"></div>
      <small>Selected</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="seat occupied"></div>
      <small>Occupied</small>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="screen"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="seat" value="A1"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A2"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A3"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A4"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A5"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A6"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A7"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A8"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A9"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A10"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A11"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A12"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A13"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A14"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A15"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A16"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A17"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A18"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A19"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A20"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A21"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A22"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A23"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A24"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A25"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A26"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A27"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A28"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A29"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A30"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="seat" value="A31"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A32"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A33"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A34"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A35"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A36"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A37"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A38"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A39"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A40"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A41"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A42"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A43"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A44"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="A45"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seatSpace"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B1"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B2"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B3"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B4"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B5"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B6"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B7"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B8"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B9"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B10"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B11"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B12"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B13"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B14"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B15"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="seat" value="B16"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B17"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B18"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B19"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B20"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B21"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B22"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B23"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B24"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B25"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B26"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B27"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B28"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B29"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B30"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B31"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B32"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B33"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B34"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B35"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B36"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B37"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B38"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B39"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B40"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B41"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B42"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B43"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B44"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="B45"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C1"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C2"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C3"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C4"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C5"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C6"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C7"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C8"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C9"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C10"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="seat" value="C11"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C12"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C13"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C14"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C15"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C16"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C17"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C18"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C19"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C20"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C21"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C22"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C23"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C24"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C25"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C26"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C27"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C28"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C29"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C30"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C31"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C32"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C33"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C34"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C35"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C36"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C37"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C38"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C39"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C40"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C41"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C42"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C43"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C44"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="C45"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="D1"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="D2"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="D3"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="D4"></div>
      <div class="seat" value="D5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="text">
    You have selected <span id="count">0</span> seats for a price of ₹<span id="price">0</span
      >
    </p>
    <button class="glow-on-hover" type="button">Submit</button>

    <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the HTML part, I want the 'value' and the 'dbid' to be passed to the JS script

```
<option value="10" dbid="2">Sport's Day 6th - 10th (10₹)</option>
```

when the submit button is pressed it should log the event 'value' and 'dbid' in the console.
if what if asking is not possible then please suggest a different way,
thank you for your help.

Comment: Can u provide a simple version of your question, please

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow.  Can your question be asked without including the CSS, and perhaps with just a couple of seats?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass data from HTML to js you can use the [`HTML data-* Attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).
so in your case, you can do something like

```
<option value="10" data-dbid="3">Sport's Day 2st - 5nd (10₹)</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

When the submit button is clicked you need to look at which option has been selected in the movie element. Here are the simplified steps you can add as appropriate to your submit code:

1. finding the movie element:

   const movie = document.querySelector('#movie');
2. finding its options and from them the selected one - which has selectedIndex

   let selected = movie.options[movie.selectedIndex];
3. then you can find its value and the dbin attribute you have given it:

   console.log(selected.value);
   console.log(selected.getAttribute('dbin');

Note: it is a standard that attributes you define yourself begin with data- so you may like to change each dbin to data-dbin.